# How can I set the content on a BindingList in a way that triggers the change event?

Tags: vb.net

Say I have a `List(of company)` called `companies`. I can create a new `BindingList` from that list like this:

```
blCompanies = New BindingList(of company)(companies)
```

But, what if I have an empty binding list

```
newBL = New BindingList(of company)
```

How can I add all the companies from `companies` to this list in a way that `newBL` will throw its change event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `BindingList` doesn't have an `AddRange` method, you'll need to call the `Add` method separately for each item you want to add, for instance:

```
For Each i As company In companies
    blCompanies.Add(i)
Next
```

Or:

```
companies.ForEach(Sub(x) blCompanies.Add(x))
```

Note, when you call the `Add` method, it will raise the `ListChanged` event, but not the `AddingNew` event.  The `AddingNew` event is only raised when you call the `AddNew` method.  If you need to determine what type of change happened when you are in the `ListChanged` event handler, you'll need to check the value of the `e.ListChangedType` property.

Comment: But my BindingList will be bound to a `DataGridView`. Doesn't that mean it will re-render each time a `company` is added?

Comment: I was thinking of making the actual `newBL` property itself implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but this seems like it's getting too complicated.

Comment: Correct, when you are using a `BindingList`, it raises the `ListChanged` event each time an item is added.  So if you add 100 items, it will raise the event 100 times.  I'm not all that familiar with the `DataGridView`, but I assume it would re-paint each time the `BindingList` raises that event.  If you want more control than that, you probably don't want to use data binding.  Data binding is useful for simple tasks, but for anything complicated, it often just makes things worse, not easier.

Comment: I'd say that I would look down my nose at anyone who would would stoop to using data-binding for any task, but that would be cruel and bigoted, so I wouldn't say it.  I can't help if I think it, though.  :)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the help. I am a newbie to VB.net and have inherited a WinForms app. All the tutorials I've found have pointed me to data binding. Could you make some suggestions to the alternative?

Comment: There's nothing *"wrong"* with data-binding, if it works well for the situation, but often the situation changes months or years later and you'll find yourself having to rewrite the code because the simple data-binding solution no longer fits the bill.  The alternative is to do it yourself.  You can add, modify, and delete data in a grid directly, just like any other control.  For instance, you can loop through all the items and add them to the grid yourself.

Comment: However, even if you do that, the grid will still re-paint each time you add an item manually.  One way to get around that, whether using data-binding or not, is to call the grid's `SuspendLayout` method before adding the items, and then call `ResumeLayout` when you are done.